# C++ output vector contents that is an object type

Tags: c++, object, vector, struct

Within my main `.cpp` file, I have a vector holding elements of type `Band`. `Band` is the name of a struct in my `implementation.cpp` file. My main file is shown below:

```cpp
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    std::vector<Band> bandsVec = readbandFile(argv[1]);
}
```

I have a corresponding `.h` file for this line of code:

```cpp
struct Band {
    std::string bandName;
    std::string listofMembers;
};

std::vector<Band> readbandFile(std::string a);
```

In my main file, I attempted to use the following enchanced `for` loop to print the vector contents:

```cpp
for (Band band: bandsVec) {
    std::cout << band << " ";
}
```

However, I get an error on the first set of `<<` operators being used:

> no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::ostream << Band

How can I print out the contents of my `bandsVec` vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define an overloaded operator `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Band&);` C++ doesn't know how to print any old struct automatically. For instance

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Band& b)
{
    return out << b.bandName << ' ' << b.listOfMembers;
}
```

If you know how to interpret it, the error message you got is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector has nothing to do with output << operator. You could write your own code to print each of the element.

```
for(const auto& band : bandsVec)
{
    std::cout<<band.bandName<<" "<<band.listofMembers<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the method to serialize your struct into the stream.
You have to provide the operator>> . It can be a member function and a separate operator. It is very rarely provided as a member function, the reason is explained in the example below.

If you prefer to keep everything inside the class you can use friend. Technically it will be a separate operator, but you place the code inside your class.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// member function
class Band1 {

    std::string name{"name"};
    std::string members{"members"};

public:
    // this (pointer to the Band itself) is implicitly passed as the first parameter and the stream is the second
    // note the difference with non-member function where the stream is the first and reference to Band is the second parameter
    // this results in a very weird call (see example in main)
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os) {
        return os << name << members;
    }
};

// operator
struct Band2 {
    std::string name{"name"};
    std::string members{"members"};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Band2& band) {
    return os << band.name << band.members;
}

// friend operator
class Band3 {

    // note the friend operator is in private section, but this is not a member function
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Band3& band) {
        return os << band.name << band.members;
    }

    std::string name{"name"};
    std::string members{"members"};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Band1{} << std::cout << std::endl; // very confusing call in case of member function
    std::cout << Band2{} << std::endl;
    std::cout << Band3{} << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```